# Способы логирования сетевого трафика, поступающего напрямую в пользовательское пространство

Tags: linux, трафик, пакет

Платформа Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64.

Сетевой трафик при получении с сетевой карты копируется сразу в пространство пользователя, для единственной программы обработчика всего сетевого трафика. Неизвестно кто обрабатывает стек tcp/ip(ядро или нет? кто знает подскажите). Исходные коды программы обработчика отсутствуют(как-то так получилось). Встал вопрос как логировать все сетевые пакеты. Существуют ли способы для перехвата пакетов не из ядра, а из пространства пользователя?

Comment: Укажите платформу

Comment: @Cerbo, Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64

Comment: Если у вас нет исходников откуда вы знаете что ПО работает именно так? Что за карта, драйвера используются?

Comment: @Cerbo, так сказано теми, кто успел совместно поработать с создателями данного ПО, но к данному приложению имеют опосредованное отношение. Код относительно старый(года 2-3), ОС обновляется постоянно. Драйвера и карту сообщу позже.